# How to add an item to JSONModel

Tags: sapui5

I need to add an object to the JSONModel in the button `press` handler.
The JSONModel is initialized in the app descriptor (manifest.json) like that:

```json
"models": {
  "invoice": {
    "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
    "uri": "model/Invoices.json"
  }
}
```

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("invoice").data.push({/*...*/});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the model is already available in your manifest and the properties already exist, you can add the item like this:

**In your Controller on click event:**

```js
var newItem = {
  "ProductName": "test add",
  "Quantity": 21,
  "ExtendedPrice": 87.2000,
  "ShipperName": "Fun Inc.",
  "ShippedDate": "2015-04-01T00:00:00",
  "Status": "A"
};
var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("invoice");
oModel.setProperty("/Invoices", oModel.getProperty("/Invoices").concat(newItem));
```

**In your manifest under `datasources` and `models`:**

```
"dataSources": {
  "invoice": {
    "uri": "./model/Invoices.json",
  }
}
....
"models": {
  "invoice": {
    "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
    "dataSource": "invoice"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var oModelInvoice = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("invoice");
var obj = {
 "ProductName": "test add",
 "Quantity": 21,
 "ExtendedPrice": 87.2000,
 "ShipperName": "Fun Inc.",
 "WeightUnit" : "G",
 "ShippedDate": "2015-04-01T00:00:00",
 "Status": "A" 
}:

oModelInvoice.setProperty("/myObject", obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE ANSWER WE SHOULD use push 
 var obj= {};

```
         obj.ProductName = "test add me";
          obj.Quantity = 120;
          obj.Status = "C";

         var oModel = this.getModel("invoice");
         var localdata = oModel.getData();
         localdata.Invoices.push(obj);
         oModel.setData(localdata);
```